# MySQL Adding two binary values stored in user defined variables

Tags: mysql, variables, binary

I have a SQL script....

```
SET @lat = 0;

SET @lat = (SELECT (CONV(SUBSTRING(data, 5,8),16,2)) FROM transaction_wtrax WHERE `show` = 0);

SET @lat = REPLACE(@lat, 1, 2);
SET @lat = REPLACE(@lat, 0, 1);
SET @lat = REPLACE(@lat, 2, 0);
```

The above results in a binary value for @lat.

I would like to add the value 1 to @lat. 
I can add two binary literals by preceding the values with 0b

ie. `Select 0b10001 + 0b1` (this works 100%)

however the following fails to add binary when you are working with user defined variables ...

`Select @lat + 0b1  or Select Concat('0b', @lat) + 0b1` (this does not work)

How can I add my @lat to 0b1?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CONV`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv) to convert it to decimal, do the add and then convert back to binary. `CONV` doesn't mind if its input value is an integer or a string.

```
SELECT CONV(CONV(@lat, 2, 10) + 1, 10, 2)
```

e.g.

```
SELECT CONV(CONV('00000100100011001110000001000111',2,10)+1,10,2)
```

Output:

```
100100011001110000001001000
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Nick, however . My Ouput = 1.0010001100111e26 (obviously based on my @lat value.

Comment: Just FYI. My value of @lat is 00000100100011001110000001000111. Your suggestion works fine and smaller values but it seems that on longer binary values, the calculation does not work. Weird.

Comment: That is weird - I've verified that on my server it displays the number as a float instead...  for your data I get a result of `1.0010001100111e26`... let me look into it some more...

Comment: Yes, that is what I get as well. Thanks Nick. I appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Deon, I think I have a solution for large binary numbers. Can you give it a try?

Comment: Hi Deon, did this help?